# file not found: libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I got an error after updating xcode to 14.3

file not found: /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/arc/libarclite_iphonesimulator.a

[error description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5Jqjc.jpg)

i added:
`config.build_settings["EXCLUDED_ARCHS[sdk=iphonesimulator*]"] = "arm64"` 
to pod file, i stopped getting the above error but i started getting Module not found errors, so i goes this fix will not work
any fix other than downgrading XCode version

i tried also downgrading OS deployment target to 11.0 still no luck